# How do I record a weightlifting exercise on an Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app, ios

On an Apple Watch Series 2 with WatchOS 4.2.3, how can I record a weightlifting session on the Workout App?

I’m currently recording my sessions as “Other”, but I’d like to categorize them as something more specific in my activity history.

Comment: What exact version of watchOS are you running?

Comment: @Monomeeth WatchOS 4.2.3. I’ve added this info to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your best bet is to go through this process:

1. On your Apple Watch open the Workout app
2. Use the crown to navigate to the Other option
3. Tap on this to begin your weightlifting exercise workout
4. After completing the workout, swipe right and tap on the red END cross
5. When the summary appears you'll see a grey <kbd>Name Workout</kbd> button - tap on that
6. Now you'll see a list of categories, initially grouped by *Popular* categories and then listed in alphabetical order
7. Use the crown to scroll through the choices and tap the one that best fits (I see that Strength Training is listed as a popular choice - perhaps that's a suitable option)
8. Now the label will appear on the Summary screen
9. Use the crown to scroll to the bottom of the summary screen and tap on the <kbd>Done</kbd> button

Now you'll find that whatever category you selected will be available in your list of main Workout options when you launch the Workout app. It also means this option can be used by the Activity app on your iPhone so that your workout history is more informative/applicable to what you're doing.

Comment: "Name Workout" is no longer shown